# npm does not install any package via VS 2013

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2013

I tried to install bower and protractor via Package Manager Console in VS 2013 and VS 2012
I am getting error

```
npm : npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor
At line:1 char:1
+ npm install protractor
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (npm http GET ht....org/protractor:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

then long list of

```
npm

http

304
 https://registry.npmjs.org/protractor

npm

http

GET
 https://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver

npm

http

GET
 https://registry.npmjs.org/saucelabs
```

List is very long.
At the end I am getting

```
bower@1.2.8 node_modules\bower
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ junk@0.2.2
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ stringify-object@0.1.7
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ abbrev@1.0.4
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ chmodr@0.1.0
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ which@1.0.5
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ osenv@0.0.3
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ graceful-fs@2.0.1
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ archy@0.0.2
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ bower-logger@0.2.1
 ....

Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ mout@0.7.1
Γö£ΓöÇΓöÇ bower-config@0.5.0 (optimist@0.6.0, mout@0.6.0)
ΓööΓöÇΓöÇ bower-registry-client@0.1.6 (request-replay@0.2.0, async@0.2.9, bower-config@0.4.5)
```

I re installed Nodejs from official website, I checked that PATH contains nodejs folder.
Any ideas appreciated.

I tried to install via regular powershell command window and it worked.

**Edit**
I tried to uninstall a package (that I installed via regular powershell window) and it worked so only install does not work....

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are using the node.js tools for Visual Studio. There's a NPMVISUAL STUDIO that you can use to install your packages, maybe it can help you. Scott Hanselman explains it too well in [this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNodejsToolsForVisualStudio.aspx).

Comment: You could install your packages using NPMVISUAL STUDIO, no?

Comment: I do not see, how. There is only Node.js interactive window, I tried but install command is not recognizable (looks like immediate window vs. package manager)

Answer (score 0):

Under your Node project, there is an item labeld "npm".  Right-click and choose "Manage npm modules..."  You can then refer to [Scott's blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingNodejsToolsForVisualStudio.aspx) which details the NPM Package Management.

[image: right click node module]

Comment: i can't see this? my context menu is only  6 items when i right click to that.

Comment: Did you install the Node.js tools for VS 2013?  https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/downloads/get/1440949

I haven't used it in awhile and have moved to VS2015 so screenshots may be out of date.

Comment: I am also unable to see this. I have Node Tools for Visual Studio 1.2

Comment: I have VS2015 and updated the screenshot for Node tools 1.2. Hope that helps.